# Hensel's Lemma for zero ring

Tags: ring-theory, hensels-lemma

Hansel's Lemma for an arbitrary ring is on [pg. 117](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Elowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf) of *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by Joseph H. Silverman:

> [image]

Here, when $I＝R$, $R$ is automatically zero ring, could you tell me why then Hensel's Lemma holds?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: if $R$ is the zero ring, then the polynomial ring $R[w]$ is also the zero ring.  Any polynomial $F(w) \in R[w]$ is zero.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Then, if assumption does not hold, the statement is true. If the polynomial $f＝0$ and $a＝0$ satisfies the assumption, zero polynomial $f$ has only root $0$ which is the limit of cushy sequence $0,0,0・・・$. So the theorem holds. My explanation is too poor..

Comment: Is this correct? I would like to hear your opinion.